# Handline curl GET request with spaces

Tags: curl

Here is the command i am using to get the data.

Tried using `%20`, `+` and also quotes. Nothing seems working.

```
curl -g -v -H "Authorization: "XXX" --request GET \
--url https://insights-api.clavistechnology.com/api/v2/search-term-results?filter\[online-store\]=amazon&\[search-term\]=250gb%20ssd \
--header 'accept: application/vnd.api+json' \
--header 'content-type: application/vnd.api+json' --globoff
```

enclosing it quotes gives `< HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST`

```
--url "https://insights-api.clavistechnology.com/api/v2/search-term-results?filter\[online-store\]=amazon&\[search-term\]=250gb ssd" \
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a few more quotes, and to remove one quote.  I got the following to give me a Not Authenticated message:

```
curl -g -v -H 'Authorization: XXX' \
  --url 'https://insights-api.clavistechnology.com/api/v2/search-term-results?filter[online-store]=amazon&[search-term]=250gb%20ssd' \
  --header 'accept: application/vnd.api+json' \
  --header 'content-type: application/vnd.api+json'
```

I replaced the double quotes with single quotes around Authorization: XXX, and removed the double quote in the middle.  I single quoted the URL too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For future readers using Windows: given the `\` to continue the command on the next line(s), I assume the question and answer are not for Windows. For Windows, [for what I've heard](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/forum/t/using-curl-or-postman-for-the-http-integration-on-windows/12467), one might need double quotes for all quoted parameters. (But: I've not tested, as I'm not on Windows myself.)